# Use coalesce function in sql to to return zero counts of records without showing any column value to be null

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

I am trying to return zero counts as results for a query. But when I am running this query, a particular column's values are returning as null.

```
select tab1.source_type,
       coalesce(tab2.numberofrecords,0) as numberofrecords,
       coalesce(dt,current_date-40) as dt,
       coalesce(client_id,client_id) as  client_id
       from  (select distinct source_type from integration_customers ) 
       as tab1
       left join
       (select count(id) as Numberofrecords, 
        source_type, Date(created_at) as dt,
        client_id
        from integration_customers ic
        where Date(created_at)= current_date-39 
        and
        source_type in 
        (select distinct "source" from integration_integrationconfig ii where status ='complete')
        group by source_type ,dt,client_id 
        order by dt desc) as tab2
        on tab1.source_type = tab2.source_type
```

But the results for this query is something like this:

[image]

I want to remove these null values and show the client id specifically for each zero record as well.

The table integration customers has the client id, created at,source type.

Comment: Since you didn't qualify your columns, we don't know what table `client_id` comes from. We would need to know the table definitions.

Comment: I have edited the columns that come from table integration customers

Comment: `coalesce(client_id,client_id)` doesn't really make sense. You still get `NULL` when `client_id` is `NULL`.